# Difference between styles of iterating over vectors and other stl containers

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Suppose there is an stl container, for the sake of simplicity I am going to use a vector declared as

After getting the answer I realized that it was because I wasn't actually iterating over `int` but a custom data structure template `T`, just making edits so someone in the future might find it easier to understand.

`std::vector <T> vec;`

Now there are two common methods to iterate over it.

1.

```
for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    /* std::cout << *it; ... */
}
```

2.

```
for(T t: vec)
{
    /* std::cout << t; ... */
}
```

Now I always assumed that both these methods were more or less same under the hood and were supposed to have similar runtime, but recently in a competition on hackerearth the second one (My usual Goto) gave TLE on the last test case and just by switching to first method I managed to get all the cases passed, did I miss something that differentiates between them or it was just a coincidence (Since actual difference between their runtime was minute, just on different side of the limit). I couldn't find anything, so if you have any links or Insights please share.

Comment: You weren't iterating over `int`s, were you?

Comment: If you had a big structure that you copied, if course that's not th same.

Comment: There are difference between `for(C c: vec)` and `for(/*const*/C& c: vec)`, the former copies, whereas the later uses reference.

Comment: Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes a copy of the variable from the vector into t:

```
for(int t: vec)
{
    /* std::cout << t; ... */
}
```

For an `int` I don't think it will be much of a difference.

But if You're using a class with copy constructors,... You could try using a reference:

```
for(int& t: vec)
{
    /* std::cout << t; ... */
}
```

And if it doesn't modify the variable, use a `const int&`

Comment: Ok So I get it, since I was actually using a custom structure as a template class, making copies was what started taking time, rather If I just reference them, it would go faster, thanks.